# cordova-plugin-fcm giving null in token with ios real device (ionic)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins

I have done these steps :

1. created project in firebase console
2. added ios app
3. bundle id and certificate.p12 uploaded
4. added this event of FCM

> ```
> FCMPluginin.getToken(function(token){
>   console.log("FCMPlugin.getToken token : ", token);
> });
> ```

this is working fine android real devices, also it is working fine on simulator (ios) but it is giving null (token) in real ios device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by enabling the keychain sharing enable from xcode > capabilities tab.